# Load LightGBM/XGBoost model to sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, xgboost, lightgbm

LightGBM and XGBoost models can be dumped to plain text files containing human-readable model structure. In the end, they are just tree ensembles.

Is there any library to load these dumped models to the scikit-learn framework, e.g. construct sklearn ensembles with same splits and values?

That could be quiet convinient as there are some nice libraries attached to sklearn API, e.g. [treeinterpreter](https://github.com/andosa/treeinterpreter).

Answer (score 1):

For XGBoost you can use the [xgbfir library](https://github.com/limexp/xgbfir) which parses the xgb model display feature interactions and ranking. Install it with:

```
pip install xgbfir
```

For lightGBM, I'm not aware of good options.  Microsoft's lightGBM library allows PMML export, so perhaps you could export then use some PMML parsers.